# How I use multi column ordering with one column in desc?

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatables, columnsorting

This is my datatable:

```
NAME   SORT
Adam
Ali    101
David  102
Laura
Will
```

I try to sort my table by the column `name` and also by the column `sort`.

The result I am looking for is:

```
NAME   SORT
David  102  
Ali    101  
Adam
Laura
Will
```

This means, everything that has a sort number should sort by the column `sort` and everything else by `name`.

This is my approach:

```
var table = $('.datatable').DataTable({
"order": [[ 0, "asc" ]],
"columnDefs": [
  {
        "targets": [ 0 ],
        "orderData": [ 0, 1 ]
      },
],
...
```

But it is not working. The columns are only sorted by `name`.
If I change the code to:

```
  var table = $('.datatable').DataTable({
    "order": [[ 0, "asc" ]],
    "columnDefs": [
      {
            "targets": [ 0 ],
            "orderData": [ 1, 0 ]
          },
    ],
    ...
```

It is considering now both columns for sorting, but the second column orders in the wrong direction:

```
NAME   SORT
Adam
Laura
Will
Ali    101  
David  102
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***UPDATE***: I missed one item in my initial post. I have now corrected the demo from this `"orderData": [ 2 ]` to this `"orderData": [ 2, 0 ]`.

Two options:

### Suggested Approach

The demo table:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var data = [
    { "name": "Adam", "sort": null }, 
    { "name": "Ali", "sort": 101 }, 
    { "name": "David", "sort": 102 }, 
    { "name": "Will", "sort": null },
    { "name": "Laura", "sort": null } 
  ];

  $("#myTable").DataTable({
    data: data,
    columns: [
      { "data": "name", "orderData": [ 2, 0 ] },
      { "data": "sort" },
      { "data": null, "visible" : false,
          "render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
            return (!row.sort ? 999 : row.sort * -1);
          } 
        }
    ],
    order: [ [ 1, "desc" ], [ 0, "asc" ] ]
  });

});
```

We have introduced a new (hidden) column, containing the following data - unhidden just for this screenshot:

[image]

The following causes this 3rd column's data to be used when you sort on column 1 (followed by the data in column 1 - index 0):

```
{ "data": "name", "orderData": [ 2, 0 ] },
```

In this case the "2" refers to column 3 - column indexing starts at 0.

### Alternative

This probably is not what you want, but I mention it because it is a simpler solution - albeit requiring more knowledge from the user.

Demo table:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var data = [
    { "name": "Adam", "sort": null }, 
    { "name": "Ali", "sort": 101 }, 
    { "name": "David", "sort": 102 }, 
    { "name": "Will", "sort": null },
    { "name": "Laura", "sort": null }
  ];

  $("#myTable").DataTable({
    data: data,
    columns: [
      { "data": "name" },
      { "data": "sort" }
    ],
    order: [ [ 1, "desc" ], [ 0, "asc" ] ]
  });

});
```

This line sets the initial sort order:

```
order: [ [ 1, "desc" ], [ 0, "asc" ] ]
```

This gives you the following when the table is first displayed:

[image]

To return to this starting point, the user has to do the following:

1) Click on the column 2 sort arrow until that column is sorted correctly.

2) While holding down the SHIFT key, click on column 1 until that column is sorted correctly.

### Notes

The alternative is more flexible, but requires the user to know about the SHIFT key for multiple column sorting.

The proposed approach will do that work automatically - but users will not be able to get a "pure" alphabetic sort on user names with this option. It may even be confusing, if they don't know why the data is ordered the way it is.